# Aligning list of items

Tags: css, list, alignment

I'm having a problem getting the text that goes with a list of items - each preceded by a letter - on an online questionnaire to align properly.  In other words, I have a list that looks like this (using the letter 'o' to represent radio buttons), where with letters such as f, i, j, etc., the radio button and accompanying text are shifted slightly but noticeably to the left:

```
a.  o Yes  o No  Asbestosis  
b.  o Yes  o No  Asthma  
c.  o Yes  o No  Chronic bronchitis  
d.  o Yes  o No  Emphysema  
e.  o Yes  o No  Pneumonia  
f.  o Yes  o No  Tuberculosis
```

Here is the HTML code, leaving out the code for items b, c, d and e for brevity's sake.

```
<div id="question20" class="indent" style="display:block;line-height:15px">
    <span class="num-bullet">3</span>Have you <em><b>ever had</b></em> any of the following pulmonary or lung problems?
    <p class="p1">a.
    <input type="hidden" xmlTag="asbestosis" is_required='yes' id="question20a" name="question20a" number="20" prerequisite="0" section="Part A. Section 2." description="3.a. Have you had asbestosis?" />
    <input type="radio" id="20y" name="20" value="Yes" style="padding-left:5em"/>Yes
    <input type="radio" id="20n" name="20" value="No"/>No
    Asbestosis
    </p>
    <div id="div_explanation20" class="indent" style="display:none;padding-left:60px">
        <input type="text" id="explanation20" name="explanation20" number="20" xmlTag="asbestosis_explanation" size="40" maxlength="40" value="Please explain" text_label="Please explain"  section="Part A. Section 2." description="3.a. Have you had asbestosis?" /><br />
    </div>  
    <p class="p1">f.
    <input type="hidden" xmlTag="tuberculosos" is_required='yes' id="question28" name="question28" number="28" section="Part A. Section 2." description="3.i. Have you had tuberculosis?" />
    <input type="radio" id="28y" name="28" value="Yes" style="padding-left:5em"/>Yes
    <input type="radio" id="28n" name="28" value="No"/>No
    Tuberculosis
    </p>
    <div id="div_explanation28" class="indent" style="display:none;padding-left:60px">
        <input type="text" id="explanation28" name="explanation28" number="28" xmlTag="tuberculosis_explanation" size="40" maxlength="40" value="Please explain" text_label="Please explain"  section="Part A. Section 2." description="3.i. Have you had tuberculosis?" /><br />
    </div>
```

Here is what I believe to be the applicable CSS code:

```
span.num-bullet { display:block; float:left; width:15px; line-height:15px; text-align:center; color:#00588a; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; background:url(../img/numbered-bullet.gif) no-repeat; margin-right:10px;}  

p.p1 {text-indent:30px}  

form div.group div.indent {margin-left:30px; clear:left;}
```

I'm in no way a CSS expert; novice at best.  Much of this was provided by a co-worker.

Thanks!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U443M/)

Comment: What do you want the final product to look like? Just no indentation on a-f?

Comment: I see now that my sample of the layout, which appeared when creating my question just as it does on my web page, appears with everything aligned properly after posting.  What I'm seeing is that with certain letters - f, i, j, for example - in the first position, the radio buttons are shifted to the left and don't align properly with the radio buttons above and below.  I want some indentation but I want the radio buttons to be aligned.  I know, as suggested in another reply, it's due to proportional fonts, but surely there's a way to get proper alignment without using a non-proportional font.

Comment: I honestly wouldn't mess with trying to align those divs. Using a list would be a much more "correct" way to do it, and will take care of the alignment for you. I might use nested lists instead.

Comment: Not trying to align the divs; I just included that in code in case that was part of problem. They only are made visible if the user selects a 'yes' radio button.  Their alignment is fine and not a concern.  It's the radio buttons that don't always line up and it just doesn't look right. I can get them aligned somewhat by including &nbsp; where necessary, but that seems like a work around that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a workaround... You could put a `<span>` around the letters and give that a specific width. That'll make it so that they all line up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue correctly then it may be resolved by using a fixed-width or monospaced font, such as Courier New, where all characters have the same width. Otherwise characters such as i,l,f etc. may appear narrower and throw off the alignment.